# Git removed commits on remote reappear

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-rebase, git-remote

We have different branches for our different versions of a project.  Somehow a section of commits from a dev branch was merged into a production branch.

We assumed it was a git stash apply error on the new branch and proceeded to remove the commits (there were only 5-6) with `git rebase -i {commit hash}^` and then removed the effected lines.

We force pushed the changes `git push -f` and all seemed well after those of us in the room pulled it down.  We made a general notice that you would have to pull before doing anything on these branches and left for the day.

This morning we came back and people who pulled this morning have the commits re-appear in their code, breaking things. Those of us who pulled last night, pull and get the fixed code.

Bitbucket doesn't show the code changes in the source code viewer, yet when we look at the commits the broken commits show in the timeline for the production branch.

Access to the repository has been revoked for everyone until we fix it so I can no longer inspect it but does anyone have any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: did you explicitly instruct your users to `recover from an upstream rebase`?  it sounds like some just typed `git pull`

Comment: oh no we just pulled, how do we do that

Comment: it's an entire section in `git rebase --help`.  Probably they can `git rebase --onto origin/<branch> HEAD~X` where they will have to manually determine X based on how many commits they had.

Comment: ahhh I see, when we pulled we did do a rebase, then when ppl this morning pulled they did a just pull thanks for the help!